# Check network status in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing app using phonegap.In my app I need to check network status .I have used following code,

```
   function checkConnection() 
{
    var networkState            = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states                  = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    console.log("network------"+networkState);               

    return networkState;             
}
```

It is working fine ,but offline mode also it is returns 3g (testing in emulator).y'day also it is working fine.Any problem with this method please guide me...

Comment: Are you sure the network emulation is off? This script works for me actual device

Comment: actual device it is working fine

Comment: It looks like there is some problem with android emulator.

Comment: ya problem with emulator.....it is working fine some other emulator.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
                                       function onDeviceReady() {
                                          pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
                                          destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
                                          checkConnection();
                                       }
                                       function checkConnection() {
                                          networkState = navigator.connection.type;
                                           var states = {};
                                            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
                                            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
                                            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
                                            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
                                            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
                                            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
                                            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
                                            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                                        }
```

Now to check the connectivity, you can put the following condition:-

```
if(networkState == Connection.NONE){
                                                                      navigator.notification.confirm('It looks like your photo could not be shared. Please try again.',onConfirmOne,'Photo Not Shared',['Ok']);
                                         }
```

Also enter the following tag in config.xml:-

```
 <feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
</feature>
```